# Centering subview on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Simply as the title says, I'm trying to center one Activity Indicator on the center of my View by doing that:

```
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

but I end up with this result:

[image]

the problem persists within all view controllers in this app, except for the last one, that really centers it as you can see:

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use AutoLayout instead of `.center`.

Comment: swap the addSubview and the activity.center lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xcode 10 / Swift 4**

It can be the hight of the tab bar is disturbing. anyways,
If your code (`.center`) doesn't work, try this:

```
activityIndicator.frame = CGRect.init(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
```

If it still doesn't work, change `y: view.frame.size.height / 2 -` *"THE HIGHT OF TAB BAR"*.

Comment: I really don't get why, but setting the frame did work! thank you.
Doesn't work for the last view tho.